# Deploying Meteor in digital ocean (ubuntu) nothing happens

Tags: meteor, digital-ocean

I am new to meteor. I want to deploy meteor app in digital ocean. I use mup deploy to deploy app. The deploy step is success but when I go to root url, the app does not load. It works in localhost. Any troubleshooting steps wold be helpful.

Comment: I found [this post](http://code.krister.ee/hosting-multiple-instances-of-meteor-on-digitalocean/) on [crater.io](http://crater.io/) - not sure if that's helpful.

Comment: From the command line you used to deploy, can you access the logs with "mup logs -n 400" and post it here? That will help us help you